# Sending client request from India location to USA Rest API

Tags: angular, rest

I have my own application which can run from any location like India, USA, Canada. But I want to send a request from my application to other country govt public rest api's. Suppose, I'm sending a request from India location to US govt public rest api's. So is it possible to send a request from India to other country govt api's?

Note: Somewhere I came to know that, If we send a request from India location to other country govt public API's, then they will block the account which my company has an account in other country govt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think this is more related to lawsit than development. But anyway, some options:

1. **Check government API's Terms & Conditions**. It is a public organization, so they should have oficial documents to inform about this. Or maybe contact them to ask.
2. **Use a proxy**. You could try to rent a VPS (Virtual Private Server), located on USA, that could act as a reverse Proxy. In other words, your app (from India), makes request to this VPS, which will contact to the government API (request originated in India, but the connections will look as national ones to government API).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sergio. Actually I'm using remote server and sending the requests.